# Understanding the で

Tags: particle-で

> 目に留まった店のショーウィンドウに、自分の姿を映してみる。雑誌で見かけて気に入ったワンピースに、フェイクファーの縁取りのケープ。ちょっと踵の高いブーツは、まだ慣れないけれど挑戦中だ。
>
> この街に来たばかりの頃はテレザや、エルンストの秘書**で**年の近い人達が見立ててくれたものを着ていたけれど、最近は自分で選んで着ている。可愛いかな、と色々向きを変えて見ていると、ウィンドウの向こうでお店のお姉さんが笑って親指を立ててくれた。

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

How should I understand the bold で? Is it like などという here?

Answer (score 3):

It is a te-form of the copula だ, so means *and*: People who are Ernst's secretaries **and** (who are) close in age.

Syntactically it is the same as 機能が豊富で処理の速いPC (PC with many functionalities and high processing power) although this で is a conjugation of na-adjective.